# I have a code where I import another code file, but the other code gets executed before my actual code runs

Tags: python-3.x

So I am making **a Voice assistant**, and then I have to **import another file**, but the file always gets **executed**.

So I know there is a **fix using an if loops** but none of the answers are **elaborate enough**.

```
#voice_assistant
import math;
import DayCal2; #DayCal is a code I made to calculate the number of days between a user input day and the current date...
```

The DayCal code starts running as an individual code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is write everything in your second module that runs right away inside a check like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_things()
```

this way, your `do_things()` function will be called if you open up this file and run it directly, BUT if you import this file, the `__name__` will not be `"__main__"` so your `do_things()` function will not be called in this case.